# Winsock - issue with connecting

Tags: c++, windows, winsock

I was building a small program to download something from a website once a day. But whenever I run my program, it outputs "WSAConnectByName: returned FALSE with error code 10109", which is WSATYPE_NOT_FOUND according to the list on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I don't really understand what I've done wrong. Does anyone mind finding my error?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>

static const TCHAR s_lpctszAddress[] = TEXT("www.google.com");

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost;

   WSADATA wsaData;
   int iWSAStartup = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

   if (!iWSAStartup)
   {
      SOCKET Socket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, NULL, 0, 0);
      if (Socket != INVALID_SOCKET)
      {
         INT iSize = sizeof(s_lpctszAddress);
         SOCKADDR saAddr;
         DWORD dwSOCKADDRLen = sizeof(saAddr);
         BOOL fConnect = WSAConnectByName(Socket, const_cast<LPWSTR>(s_lpctszAddress), TEXT("/"), &dwSOCKADDRLen, &saAddr, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
         if (fConnect == TRUE)
         {
            cout << "Success!";
         }
         else
         {
            cout << format("WSAConnectByName: returned FALSE with error code %1%.") % WSAGetLastError() << endl;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         cout << format("WSASocket: returned INVALID_SOCKET with error %1%.") % WSAGetLastError() << endl;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      cout << format("WSAStartup: returned %1% with error %2%.") % iWSAStartup % WSAGetLastError() << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Service type is not valid : this altered line of code worked for me.

```
BOOL fConnect = WSAConnectByName(Socket, const_cast<LPWSTR>(s_lpctszAddress),
   TEXT("http"), &dwSOCKADDRLen, &saAddr, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Per the [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741557%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> A service name is a string alias for a
>   port number. For example, “http” is an
>   alias for port 80 defined by the
>   Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF)
>   as the default port used by web
>   servers for the HTTP protocol.
>   Possible values for the servicename
>   parameter when a port number is not
>   specified are listed in the following
>   file:
>
> %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\services

Comment: Oh, thanks. I thought it was just supposed to be a subdirectory or something.

Answer (score 1):

You need a port/service name as the third parameter.